# SSH : How can I run a script immediately after put only login as (username)

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

To secure ssh connections
I wrote a script that sent otp code when trying to connect
When the user enters his username (login as :) he will receive the mail from the otp

Where should I put my script so that it is executed just before that can enter its password?

[image]

Comment: I think you'd need to edit PAM's login routines, but I've never done this myself.

Comment: How i can to it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer on [askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/724796/18619), you need to use PAM_Exec to achieve this.

> You can use [PAM](https://askubuntu.com/a/724796/18619) for this. The PAM configuration for the SSH
>   service is in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. To run a command before anything in
>   the login process, add something like:

```
auth [default=ignore] pam_exec.so /path/to/some/script
```

Comment: Thanks for the support djsmiley2k and DavidPostill

it is working now

Comment: Awesome :) I like the idea of what you've mentioned, maybe you can document it somewhere so I can look at implementing it myself?

Comment: No worries I would do the necessary
I'll send it to you